# Highcharts, how to move from jsfiddle to html

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a working chart in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e3so7j1d/33/, I'm trying to move this to a web page:https://jsfiddle.net/e3so7j1d/38/, how do I need to modify the javascript so that it displays, i.e. what is the magic that jsfiddle hides when it separates the javascript from the html? Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    magic
Highcharts.chart('container', {

});
</script>
```

Comment: The Javascript in those 2 jsfiddles is definitionally different. For example, the first (working) jsfiddle does not start with `Highcharts.chart('container', {`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is a basic way of initialising a chart:

```
<div id='containder'> </div>

<script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
...
});
</script>
```

It is a constructor method where the first parameter is
a reference to the div (chart place) and the second is an options object (chart options).

At your first fiddle, you create *gaugeOptions* object with some options. Then, the chart is created by the contructor, but you also merge *gaugeOptions* with *provided options* into the one options object (as a second parameter).

In the second fiddle, you copied JS script, but you also wraped it as a second parameter of a contructor, but it doesn't make sense.

The JavaScript Tab in the JSFiddle works as a normal `<sript>` tag in the HTML. If you copy your JS code into HTML, it should be placed in the `<script>` tag without any unnecessary wrapping.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k3sut05r/

**API References**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options

Comment: Thank you magdalena, exactly what I needed.  My biggest issue is lack of Javascript knowledge, this has helped me understand.